# Stay at current position at form submit?

Tags: javascript

How do I stay on the current position when the form is submitted instead of comin to the top of the page?

```
     <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#ok').click(function(){
          var dt=$('#form').serialize();
          $.post('data.php',dt,function(data){
          })
         });
      });
      </script>


<script>
 function submitnow() {
        $('#form').submit();
}
</script>

<div onclick='submitnow();'></div>

    <form action='' method='post' id='form'>
            <input type="hidden" id="ok" name='ok' value="ok">
    </form>
```

UPDATE
Im very sorry i forgot to post that i submit the form with onclick. but i thought it only was to add the code into the function but that wasnt the case :/

```
<script>

    function submitnow() {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').submit(function(){
      var dt=$(this).serialize();
      $.post('data.php',dt,function(data){
      });

        return false;
     });
  });
}
  </script>
```

This is the code i currently use and it scrolls me up to top:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').submit(function(){
      var dt=$(this).serialize();
      $.post('data.php',dt,function(data){
      });

        return false;
     });
  });
  </script>

<script>
 function submitnow() {
        $('#form').submit(function(){

        });
}
</script>

 <div onclick='submitnow();'></div>

<form action='' method='post' id='form'>
        <input type="hidden" id="ok" name='ok' value="ok">
</form>
```

Comment: no, the 
`$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').submit(function(){
      var dt=$(this).serialize();
      $.post('data.php',dt,function(data){
      });

        return false;
     });
  });`
 must be placed outside of the function. 
Then inside the function submitnow() you can call `$("#form").submit();` that fire the submit

Comment: hm okay thats what i did from the beginning but i dont get it why the page still scrolls up on submit :S

Comment: no, at the beginning you handled the .click event of the button (see your question). You must handle the .submit event with return false (see my comment) or your page is reloaded and scroll up

Comment: Oh i see. But i use the .submit now and it still scrolls..
ill update the post with the current code in a sec

Comment: in submitnow() function you must Trigger the submit, not handle the submit. 
`function submitnow() { $('#form').submit(); } `
I tested and .post() (aka ajax request) is called correctly. If it continue to not working as you expected please provide a link of the page or a complete jsfiddle (not this little sample)

Comment: I can fetch the value and echo it and everything but i still get scrolled up. Ok ill make a jsfiddle in a sec

Comment: Probably is because of some other code because this one correctly made an ajax request (and return false in the submit) so it souldn't change or scolling your page, unless other code do it. waiting for the jsfiddle

Comment: @DarioPicco Now it actually dont scrollup anymore im not really sure what i edited lol. But now it cannot fetch the values anymore..
It getting late tho so i ill get into it tomorrow. Thanks for your help and patient :D

Comment: Ok but if `.submit()` helped you in the solution (insteand of the .click()) please flag my answere as the correct one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To catch the submit event and call ajax instead of submit form use

```
$("#form").submit(function () {
    var dt = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('data.php',dt,function(data) {
    });

    return false;
});
```

Thanks @dfsq for the improvements

**UPDATE:**

see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/er5x4jb5/2/) for a working ajax submit

Comment: The best answer: proper use of onsubmit event instead of button onclick. Could be even better without requery DOM: `$(this).serialize()`.

Comment: Thanks. Expecially in this example where "ok" is not a button but an hidden type.

Comment: Hm i updated my post also. I dont know if thats what making it to not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ok').click(function(e){
      e.prenevtDefault();
      var dt=$('#form').serialize();
      $.post('data.php',dt,function(data){
      });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do three things:

*1)* (Does not need JavaScript) Add a named anchor at the position in the page where you want to scroll to when the page is submitted and add the name to the action. This will cause the page to scroll to that position. For this to work you need to know where you want the page to scroll to when you create the page.

```
<a id="tohere"></a>
<form action="#tohere" ...
```

*2)* (Needs JavaScript) Use an ajax form submit so the page is not reloaded (See the other answers for JQuery examples on how to do that)

*3)* (Needs JavaScript) Store the current position in a cookie or local storage and have JavaScript read the data and have it scroll to that position on page load.